# Could we deploy web site to azure web app use "MSDeployUseChecksum" config?

Tags: asp.net, azure, msbuild

Actually,I got error when I deploy use "MSDeployUseChecksum" ,if remove "MSDeployUseChecksum", deploy will successed. C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.targets(4295,5): msdeploy error ERROR_PROXY_GATEWAY: Web deployment task failed. (Could not connect to the remote computer ("dev-cms.scm.didix-dev-ase.p.azurewebsites.net") using the specified process ("Web Management Service"). This can happen if a proxy server is interrupting communication with the destination server. Disable the proxy server and try again.  Learn more at: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_PROXY_GATEWAY.

pubxml file

[image]